# PostgreSQL - Check foreign key exists when doing a SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

Suppose I have the following data:

Table `some_table`:

```
some_table_id | value | other_table_id
--------------------------------------
1             | foo   | 1
2             | bar   | 2
```

Table `other_table`:

```
other_table_id | value
----------------------
1              | foo
2              | bar
```

Here, `some_table` has a foreign key to column `other_table_id` from `other_table` into the column of some name.

With the following query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE other_table_id = 3;
```

As you see, `3` does not exists in `other_table` This query obviously will return 0 results.

**Without doing a second query**, is there a way to know if the foreign key that I am using as a filter effectively does not exist in the `other_table`?

Ideally as an error that later could be parsed (as it happends when doing an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` with a wrong foreign key, for example).

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The answer to your question is "yes", but you give no indication of how you want this information.

Comment: Edited, let me know if this needs to be clarified

Answer (score 5):

You can exploit a feature of PL/pgSQL to implement this ***very cheaply***:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_select_from_some_tbl(int)
  RETURNS SETOF some_table AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * 
   FROM   some_table 
   WHERE  other_table_id = $1;

   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE WARNING 'Call with non-existing other_table_id >>%<<', $1;
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

A final `RETURN;` is optional in this case.

The `WARNING`is only raised if your query doesn't return any rows. I am not raising an `ERROR` in the example, since this would roll back the whole transaction (but you can do that if it fits your needs).

We've added a code example [to the manual with Postgres 9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 3):

If you perform an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on `some_table`, specifying an `other_table_id` value that does not in fact exist in `other_table`, then you will get an error arising from violation of the foreign key constraint.  `SELECT` queries are therefore your primary concern.

One way you could address the issue with `SELECT` queries would be to transform your queries to perform an outer join with `other_table`, like so:

```
SELECT st.* 
FROM
  other_table ot
  LEFT JOIN some_table st ON st.other_table_id = ot.other_table_id
WHERE st.other_table_id = 3;
```

That query will always return at least one row if any `other_table` row has `other_table_id = 3`.  In that case, if there is no matching `some_table` row, then it will return exactly one row, with that row having all columns `NULL` (given that it selects only columns from `some_table`), even columns that are declared not null.

If you want such queries to raise an error then you'll probably need to write a custom function to assist, but it can be done.  I'd probably implement it in PL/pgSQL, using that language's `RAISE` statement.

Comment: I would implement that with plpgsql, too. In fact, I just did.