# How to return a value from a function if no value is found

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, null, plpgsql

I'm attempting to return `0.0` if the following function does not return anything:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_height(firstn VARCHAR, lastn VARCHAR)
  RETURNS FLOAT AS
$$
DECLARE
    height FLOAT = 0.0;
BEGIN
    SELECT into height AVG(((p.h_feet * 12) + p.h_inches) * 2.54)
    FROM player p
    WHERE p.firstname = firstn AND p.lastname = lastn; 

    RETURN height;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've tried searching for it and found that `COALESCE` does not work. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Table structure:

```
 create table player(
                     firstname text
                    ,lastname text
                    ,h_feet INT
                    ,h_inches INT
                    );
```

Example data:

```
  insert into player values ('Jimmy','Howard',6,2);
```

Comment: Yeah, I do. I found out that I had renamed my function after adding COALESCE to my function and I was accidentally using the old function. I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script I used. As you can see I run PostgreSQL 9.4.1. 
I used HeidiSQL to launch the queries.
Are you sure that you correctly updated your function?
I just noted that you used a different function ('player_height') in a comment instead of 'get_height' in you original post.

```
select version();
-- PostgreSQL 9.4.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

delimiter //

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_height(firstn VARCHAR, lastn VARCHAR)         
RETURNS FLOAT AS $$
DECLARE
height FLOAT = 0.0;
BEGIN
    SELECT into height AVG(((p.h_feet * 12) + p.h_inches) * 2.54)
    FROM players p
    WHERE p.firstname = firstn AND p.lastname = lastn; 
        return coalesce(height, 0.0);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

delimiter;

CREATE TABLE players (
     firstname varchar(40),
     lastname  varchar(40),
     h_feet int,
     h_inches int);


insert into players values ('Jimmy', 'Howard', 6, 2);

select * from get_height('Jimmy', 'Howard');
-- gives 187.96

select * from get_height('Random', 'Guy');
-- gives 0
```

Comment: I'm using postgreSQL 8.4.20 and unable to update it as this is not my server. Could this possibly be why this isn't working?

Answer (score 10):

#### Explanation

The root of the problem is the fuzzy definition of "not anything".

> if the following function does not return anything

**`NULL` is not *nothing***, it's just unknown what it is exactly. "Nothing" in terms of SQL would rather be **no row** - nothing returned at all. That typically happens when no qualifying row is found. But when using **aggregate functions**, that cannot happen because, [per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

> ... these functions return a null value when no rows are selected.

`avg()` returns `NULL` when no rows are found (so not "nothing"). You get a row with a `NULL` value as result - which **overwrites** your init value in the code you demonstrate.

### Solution

Wrap the result in `COALESCE`. Demonstrating a much simpler SQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_height_sql(firstn varchar, lastn varchar)
  RETURNS float
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
SELECT COALESCE(avg(((p.h_feet * 12) + p.h_inches) * 2.54)::float, 0)
FROM   player p
WHERE  p.firstname = firstn
AND    p.lastname = lastn
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5e397594c9e9ae7eb3c20d7c8f73bc2e)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4d5cd/1)</sub>

The same can be used in a PL/pgSQL function. This function can be `STABLE`, might help with performance in the context of bigger queries.

### Other cases

If you actually *can* get **no row** from a query, a simple `COALESCE` **would fail**, because it's never executed.

For a **single value** result you can just wrap the whole query like:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT some_float FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 1), 0) AS result
```

- [How to display a default value when no match found in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200462/how-to-display-a-default-value-when-no-match-found-in-a-query/8200473#8200473)

PL/pgSQL has the ability to check before actually returning from the function. This works for **multiple rows with one or more columns**, too. There is an [example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4.2) demonstrating the use of `FOUND`:

```sql
...
RETURN QUERY SELECT foo, bar ...;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RETURN QUERY VALUES ('foo_default'::text, 'bar_default'::text);
END IF;
...
```

Related:

- [Return setof record (virtual table) from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955167/return-setof-record-virtual-table-from-function/17247118#17247118)
- [PostgreSQL - Check foreign key exists when doing a SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155188/postgresql-check-foreign-key-exists-when-doing-a-select/29158104#29158104)

To always return **exactly one row**, you can also use **pure SQL**:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT 'foo_default', 'bar_default'
LIMIT  1;
```

If the first `SELECT` returns no row, the second `SELECT` returns a row with defaults.

Comment: so great to find an answer! COALESCE in postgresql works way different from sql server... thank you, sir! 

Answer (score 0):

`return coalesce(height, 0::decimal(10,2));` should do the trick

Comment: @user3376703 why does this solution not work? I just tried this and it worked well.

Comment: Just attempted SELECT * FROM player_height('DNE','DNE'); and it simply returned an empty column.

Comment: SELECT player_height('DNE', 'DNE'); works fine here.

Comment: You using postgres? Maybe there's a difference? I really have no idea why.

Comment: your select needs to contain the function call. `select player_height('dne', 'dne') as height`

Answer (score 0):

try `not found` condition

```
SELECT ... into ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...; 

if not found then
  RETURN 0;
end if;
```