# Making sure a row for a foreign key exists when filtering results with it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make sure a row referenced by a key used as a filter on another table exists when querying for results - without having to query twice to save network roundtrips.

Say we have two tables, Owner and Pet with a one to many relationship (one owner for zero to many pets, no pet is without an owner). A simple filter on the owner will return zero rows for both the case where an existing owner has no pets and the case where the owner does not exist. The easy way to differentiate the two cases would be to first query for the owner, but that seems wasteful.

```py
def get_pets(owner)
    if not query(f"select id from owner where id = '{owner}'"):
        raise OwnerNotFound()
    return query(f"select * from pet where owner_id = '{owner}'")
```

Is there a way to embed this condition into a query like this, and to differentiate cases where the foreign key doesn't exist from it existing but no results are found? I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29155188/7089239) that had answers about raising with PL/pgSQL or left joining to the table, but I'd like to know if there's a way of doing that within a query and without changing the result set.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer. I've read the above several times now, but I can't figure out what the question is about,

Comment: @jarlh Added a Python example, hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Do owner LEFT JOIN pet. Will give you all owners, with or without pet, and their pets (if any.)